# Drawing white on android canvas makes canvas darker

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm working on an android app of mine, but there is a small problem I'm having that is limiting its functionality. I'm using the android canvas to draw an animation to the screen (for a live wallpaper), but whenever I try drawing using `Canvas.drawColor()` with a color like `#01ffffff` (the last two digits are the alpha level), the canvas gets darker! How can that be? I'm drawing white over the canvas, albeit a very transparent white, but still a white. How can it be getting darker?

The color is getting drawn every frame. It is used to provide a fade to white animation, but it doesn't fade to white.

My code:

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    ...

    private void draw() {

        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);


        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            if (visible) {
                handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, refreshRate);
            }
            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {

                    canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
                }

            } finally {
                if (canvas != null)
                    try{
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }

        }
                ...
    }
```

The `draw()` method is used to draw my wallpaper to the screen and within it has a call to `canvas.drawColor()`. The variable named `backgroundColor` is initialized to the color `#01ffffff`. So does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix this? Thanks! (And any syntax errors in the code, like missing brackets, are probably due to my poor copy and pasting skills.)

Comment: Aren't the *first* two digits for the color's alpha? At least that's how `Color.FromArgb()` works in c#... that would give you a blue-ish white? Sorry not familiar with javascript. That's javascript right?

Comment: Sorry, that's not the problem. I was thinking #rrggbbaa when I wrote that. In the code that actually defines the color, it defines it correctly with alpha first. Thanks, though. And it's Java.

Answer (score 0):

Android color resources are defined with the first two digits as the transparency values. That may be your problem (as retailcoder suspected).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The declarations in my code are correct and define the color with alpha as the first value. I wrote the colors in my example off the top of my head. I'm used to the #rrggbbaa style. Anyways, that's not the problem.